# Find $a$ given $s=\frac12at^2$ and the values of $s$ and $t$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't figure out how to do this type of math problem ...

[image: pic of problem here]

Not even sure what to search for on google to find proper info to learning it. sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that $s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$ and that $s=2376$ and $t=12$ make the equation true, that implies that:

$$2376=\frac{1}{2}\cdot a \cdot (12)^2$$

From here, it is simple algebra to isolate $a$ to find its value.

Try multiplying both sides by two and dividing both sides by $12^2$...

Comment: +1 for the patient, constructive answer. Just saw it, and `Not even sure what to search for on google to find proper info to learning it` floored me.

Comment: dxiv i've been out of school for almost 30 years, and this is part of a math class i have to take. sorry for the noob question ..... thank you very much JMoravitz